# css square border with gap in border bottom

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to replicate this mock up design.

Design:

[image: Mock up design]

Current:

[image: current progress]

Is there a way to make sure the "Shop All" ignores the overflow:hidden, but the before and after obey the overflow:hidden?

Or is there another method I can try to implement this?

## Html

```
<div id="outer">
  <div id="opaq">
  <div id="inner">
    <h1>Performance Parts</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi efficitur in arcu at placerat. Aenean sed lorem tincidunt, maximus purus eget, ornare metus. Nam interdum lobortis imperdiet. Nunc gravida urna urna. Vestibulum vitae lectus leo. Etiam fermentum nunc vel nulla tincidunt, sit amet molestie lectus pulvinar.</p>
    <div id="shop">Shop all</div>
  </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

## Css

```
#outer{
  max-width:500px;
  text-align:center;
  background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRNyPOuKMHtvXNa5dnlc8xGXvW-nVfguLdlj9sj4-K6cTA0Zbf7");

}
#opaq{
  background-color: rgba(48, 44, 44, 0.7);
  padding:5px;
}
#inner{
  border:1px solid red;
  margin:10px;
  color:white;
  border-bottom:none;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#shop{
  position:relative;
  top:8px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#shop:after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  top: 9px;
  width: 600px;
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
#shop:before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  top: 9px;
  width: 600px;
  right: 100%;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oBXPPE
It wouldn't let me post more than two links. Here is a codepen of current progress.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.wrapper {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), rgba(0, 0, 0, .3)), url(http://beerhold.it/400/300);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
fieldset {
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  margin-top: .7em;
  transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 180deg);
  border: 3px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);
}
legend {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  font-weight: 700;
}
legend span,
fieldset .text {
  display: block;
  transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 180deg);
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 0 4px black;
  padding: 0 1em;
}
legend span {
  color: yellow;
}
fieldset .text {
  height: 100%;
}
fieldset .text h1 {
  padding: .3em 0;
  text-align: center;
}
fieldset .text p {
  line-height: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <fieldset>
    <legend align="center"><span>SHOP ALL</span>
    </legend>
    <div class="text">
      <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut a justo nisl. Phasellus consequat tincidunt elit, sed interdum nibh blandit ut. Nunc augue erat, rutrum ac vehicula nec, pulvinar in eros.
      </p>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: This is perfect. I had just figured out a solution but it's not nearly as clean as this is. I was unaware of the fieldset property but appears is exactly what I needed.

Comment: @comato fieldset is meant for forms :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset be aware when you use a trick :)

Comment: @GCyrillus Yea, I noticed that. Are there potential problems with this method?

Comment: @comato Some old version of browsers not supported ex. `transform: rotate3d();` - http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d

Comment: @AndreyFedorov perhaps I accepted the answer too quickly. Some of these other answers seem like they work in a less "hacky" fashion. I did check caniuse %'s before accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may try a negative margin and some flex to draw side borders, and it will keep a coherent HTML with title coming first in the code :

```css
div {
  margin:2em;
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:column;
  text-align:center;
  border:solid;
  border-bottom-color:transparent;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2em rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  }
div h2 {
  order:1;
  display:flex;
  margin:0 0 -0.6em 0;
  font-variant:small-caps;
  }
h2:before,
h2:after {
  content:'';
  flex:1;
  border-bottom:solid;
  margin:auto 1em auto -3px ;
  }
  h2:after {
  margin: auto -3px auto 1em;
    }
  p {padding:0.25em 0.5em;}
  html {background:url(http://lorempixel.com/800/600/city/6);
  background-size:cover;
  color:white;
  text-shadow:0 0 1px black;
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>
  <h2>shop all</h2>
  <p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris
    placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis
    tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
    Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: "coherent HTML with title coming first in the code"

It's always going to be "Shop All" in the gap not the title so it doesn't matter that it comes first.

Comment: @comato , okay , looked like a title or subtitle to me , at least an em styled , or is that going to be a link ? :) but for sure I do not see where it can be legend. :) my advise, your choice, nobody is wrong or right, but i still believe it is here a matter of style and not using some html elements for what it looks like.;)    .....    Just updated the snippet with a subtitle that you can put anywhere in the container ....

Answer (score 0):

Use this **css**; notice i have added comments to the code i change or added

```
    #outer{
  max-width:500px;
  text-align:center;
  background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRNyPOuKMHtvXNa5dnlc8xGXvW-nVfguLdlj9sj4-K6cTA0Zbf7");

}
#opaq{
  background-color: rgba(48, 44, 44, 0.7);
  padding:5px;
}
#inner{
  border:1px solid red;
  margin:10px;
  color:white;
  border-bottom:none;


}

#shop{
  position:relative;
  top:8px;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index:200; /*added*/



}
#shop:after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  top: 9px;
  width: 364%; /* changed */
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: 15px;

}
#shop:before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  top: 9px;
  width: 364%; /* changed */
  right: 100%;
  margin-right: 15px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

border split into table cells:

```css
 body
 {
  font-family:arial;
  background-image:url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRNyPOuKMHtvXNa5dnlc8xGXvW-nVfguLdlj9sj4-K6cTA0Zbf7");
  background-size:cover;
  margin:0px;
 }

 .box div
 {
  border:0px solid RGBa(255,255,255,0.5);
 }

 .shade
 {
  background-color:RGBa(50,50,50,0.7);
  padding:20px;
  position:fixed;
  top:0px;
  right:0px;
  bottom:0px;
  left:0px;
 }

 h1
 {
  text-align:center;
  text-transform:uppercase;
 }

 .bottomborder
 {
  display:table;
  table-layout:fixed;
 }

 .box .left
 {
  width:50%;
  border-width:0px 0px 2px 2px;
 }

 .box .right
 {
  width:50%;
  border-width:0px 2px 2px 0px;
 }

 .box .col
 {
  display:table-cell;
 }

 .shopall
 {
  padding: 0px 15px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  color:RGB(200,150,0);
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:20px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
 }

 .box
 {
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  width:1100px;
  margin-top:15px;
  max-width: 100%;
 }

 .box .content
 {
  padding:5px 55px 10px 55px;
  border-width:2px 2px 0px 2px;
  border-top-left-radius:0px;
  border-top-right-radius:0px;
  color:white;
 }
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="shade">
  <div class="box">
   <div class="content">
    <h1>Performance & Parts </h1>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi efficitur in arcu at placerat. Aenean sed lorem tincidunt, maximus purus eget, ornare metus. Nam interdum lobortis imperdiet.
   </div>
   <div class="bottomborder">
    <div class="left col">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
     <div class="shopall">
      shop all
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right col">
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```