# How to create a gap on div border?

Tags: css

[image]

[image]

How can I cut out a piece of the border around the strawberry image so that it matches the design I have been given?

Div has a standard border and the image is transparent png positioned absolutely.

Comment: Please can you provide some code?

Comment: add Jsfiddle or at least code if you want help

Comment: This is a very common question and should be answered. No need for any code, it is just a div which needs a specific border. I have the answer [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ptc68dr0/), but cannot post it at this time. Hope it helps someone.

Comment: @skobaljic legend many thanks!!!

Comment: @skobaljic Can you find a duplicate question here on SO? Closing as a duplicate (with or without an answer) would be more useful to future readers than closing as on hold.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41526444/css-square-border-with-gap-in-border-bottom) has some similar answers.